# How to make C function dynamically exported

Tags: gcc, linker, dynamic-linking

My application works with static library which has extensions API. The API is able to call extension init function from the external shared library or from the "local" binary. That is I can include extension init function statically in to the main executable binary.

The local function is searched by `dlsym` call and init function should be dynamically exported from the main binary. That is following `nm` call:

```
nm -CD <binary>
```

should list my init function.

Let's assume init function has this signature:

```
int init_func(INIT_STRUCT *);
```

This function is not called directly - it is only supposed to be loaded by `dlsym` call.

So I have two related question:

1. how to force linker to not exclude this function from the generated binary?
2. how to force compiler/linker to export this function dynamically?

(I use `gcc` to compile and link my program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will post an answer based on previous comments.

To make all functions dynamically exported: `-rdynamic`.

For a single function to be always linked (even if not referenced) you need to add `-u<function>` to the link line.

To link all functions (even unreferenced) use `--whole-archive`. To return to the normal linking use `--no-whole-archive`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately default behavior of GNU toolchain is to not export symbols from executables by default (as opposed to shared libraries which default to exporting all their symbols). You can use a big-hammer `-rdynamic` flag which tells linker to export *all* symbols from your executable file. A less intrusive solution would be to provide explicit exports file via `-Wl,--dynamic-list` when linking (see example usage in [Clang sources](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/4920d3228938c5ca6d6dd267da640e9ff65b6802/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp#L3180)).

Comment: Thank you for the info. Now I use `-rdynamic`. Unfortunately to avoid eliminating init function by th elinker I need to explicitly reference it in the code. Something like this: `void* unused = &extension_init; (void)(unused);` It would be great to have better way.

Comment: @igor.sol Do you link `extension_init` from static library? In that case linker wouldn't link object file if there's no reference unless you surround `-lxyz` with `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group`.

Comment: @yugr Surrounding `-lxyz` with `--{start,end}-group` has *no effect* on whether the object is pulled into the link or not. What you need is `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive`.

Comment: For a single function, a simpler solution is to add `-uextension_init` to the link line.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks, fixed. Can you make your last suggestion an answer so that we could +1 it?