# symbol lookup error undefined symbol on shared library calling main executable function

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I have an already compiled linux executable, which loads "libA.so"

I used elfpatch on the executable to add another needed library "libB.so"

on my libB.so I can call any function that exists in LibA.so without any problem. But if I try to call a function from the main executable I get "symbol lookup error undefined symbol"

Is there a way for me to compile libB.so to access the functions in main executable? or my only choice is to access that function using dlopen?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to compile libB.so to access the functions in main executable?

Not without rebuilding the main executable. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973611/50617).

> or my only choice is to access that function using dlopen?

That isn't an option, `dlopen` will *also* fail to find the function in the main executable if that function is not exported from it.

Comment: tnx for the reply, on IDA the function is in the exported list. But dlsym indeed fails to find it.

Comment: will the address of a funcion in my lib will always have the same offset relative to the main executable? can I look with gdb the offset of the function in the main executable, look in gdb offset of a function in my lib, calculate the difference, and then in my lib get the address of a function in my lib, and calculate the address of the address in the main executable using the offset I got in step 1 ?? and call the function like that?

Comment: @AlvaroHernandorena The offset will be the same only if 1. you disable ASLR for this process (or globally) and 2. the process is deterministic (e.g. there are no threads) before `libA.so` is loaded.

Comment: Tnx I will try and see what happens =)

Comment: So the address of the lib functions changed relative to the address of the main executable address according to gdb. T_T .

Comment: LibA uses some imported functions from main excutable. And I can access LibA functions from LibB, is there a way for me to get the address which libA uses for the imported functions from main executable? get the pointer and use that ass offset reference to get other functions in the main executable and use them in LibB ???

Comment: ahhh I listed the main executable exported functions, and I can dlsym one of them without problem, so in theory with the pointer of one of those exported functions I can GDB the offset from that to the function I want, and call it? gonna try...

Answer (score 0):

Ansering my old question I think in this project I was able to call a function from the main executable by address, literaly by address in the linux project I was working the main executable was always loaded in a relative address so I just used IDA , got the right address of the function, built a definition to the function with a absolute address and it worked. Also works in win32 if is not using some fancy memory address thing.